# Asking for a resource for past papers of the AIME

Tags: geometry

I know that AOPS is the go-to site for this sort of request but seemingly the printable PDF of the papers is not available there(already checked). It would be really helpful if there was a website from where you could download the question paper PDFs.
Sorry there isn't a specific tag for this so I just put on geometry
Thanks!

Comment: Is the browser's print option acceptable (e.g. on Chrome right click and 'Print')? You can also right click 'inspect element' and delete certain divs to clean up [the page](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2023_AIME_II_Problems) before printing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [compendium](http://www.toomates.net/biblioteca/CompendiumAIME.pdf) of all the AIME problems from 1983 to 2023.

Comment: Thanks, man appreciate it.